# border-bottom dropping entire div

Tags: html, css

Alright so the problem is this, when I hover over the li:a my entire div will drop down a bit and then come back once I finish hovering. Im just trying to set it so it will just show the border-bottom without dropping the entire div a bit down

```
<div id="header_left">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

and the css configuration is

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Nevermind, fixed. I had to increase the divs size

Answer (score 1):

just add a transparent border to the none hovered state of your element.

like this:

```
li a {
 border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

this will help getting rid of the bumpiness on hover.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the individual menu item hovered on to show the border at the bottom then you might want to set an ID for each menu item and specify what it does in css on hover. As it is right you are targeting everything which is why the whole thing drops on hover. Its an easy fix, just needs a few more lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Always adds "box-sizing: border-box" to include borders and padding inside box model
2. Set default transparent border and change only the color on hover

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

li a:hover {
    border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="header_left">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```